# Arrow object appears only once in visual mode in MQL4

Tags: mql4

I'm an MQL4 newbie and would like to draw an arrow each time a simple trigger is made.
I don't understand why in the attached code below the arrow appears only once while the comment is displayed every time the trigger is made.
How can I solve this issue?

```
#property copyright "Copyright 2022, MetaQuotes Software Corp."
#property link      
#property version   "1.00"
#property strict
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
  {
//---
   
//---
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
  {
//---
   
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
  {
//---
   double UpBarPlace1 = Close[1]>Open[1];
   double UpBarPlace2 = Close[2]>Open[2];
   double UpBarPlace3 = Close[3]>Open[3];
   
   double DwBarPlace1 = Close[1]<Open[1];
   double DwBarPlace2 = Close[2]<Open[2];
   double DwBarPlace3 = Close[3]<Open[3];
   
 
   if(UpBarPlace1 == 1)
      {
        Comment ("Sell for 2 range size target ");
        ObjectCreate(_Symbol,"Arrow", OBJ_ARROW,0,TimeCurrent(),Close[1]);       
                
      } else 
      {
        Comment("Ambiguous");  
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `object_name` (second parameter in `ObjectCreate` function) param must by **unique** for each object.
In your code, the `object_name` is always equal `"Arrow"`, and this is the reason why the arrow appears only once.

For example, you can create a global counter and iterate it on every arrow create trigger.

```
ObjectCreate(_Symbol,"Arrow_" + IntegerToString(arrowIndexingCounter), OBJ_ARROW,0,TimeCurrent(),Close[1]); 
arrowIndexingCounter++;
```

> object_name -> Name of the object. The name must be unique within a chart, including its subwindows.

[ObjectCreate function docs](https://docs.mql4.com/objects/objectcreate)

Comment: Thanks, there is a need to remove the '"' from IntegerToString(arrowIndexingCounter)"

Comment: Thanks, I was writing this without IDE and didn't pay attention to it, corrected.